# Updating the cached files in Distributed Cache in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a small set of files that are cached and distributed to a map reduce job via DistributedCache.
The cached files will need a periodic update in the future. I am wondering if it is possible to update the cached files without restarting the map reduce job.

I read about DistributedCache tracking the modification timestamps of the cached files. Will that be useful to update the files when it is not used by the map reduce job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cached files are copied to HDFS at the time of the submission of the job and then later copied locally to the local node by the different task trackers before they spawn M/R tasks. So, the files in the distributed cache can't be changed while the job is running.

Comment: Thanks for that. If it cannot be modified, what could be the use of DistributedCache tracking the modification timestamps?

Comment: From [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/DOC/Hadoop+Tutorial) - DistributedCache tracks the modification timestamps of the cached files. Clearly the cache files should not be modified by the application or externally while the job is executing.